# Form submit by enter key except in textarea in javascript?

Tags: javascript, key, form-submit

I have this form where it submits by pressing enter key.

I want it to function except for textarea, where it should has it usual behavior adding a new line in text-area

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default behavior is that the form doesn't submit if you press enter inside a textarea as seen in the [following live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ehQ8X/). It simply adds a new row inside the textarea. You don't need any javascript for this. On the other hand if the the user presses enter while inside a normal textbox the form is submitted.

Comment: well yet sadly I have few input fields that i requires to do a form submit. so by document.captureEvenet(KEYPRESS)  I'm submiting the form. Is there anyway I can override that for only this text area?

Comment: @Macon, so you want to have some input fields that submit the form and others that don't?

Comment: exactly, there's already a general code hook into the document object which handles it for all the pages.